# explosion shockwave effect on entire screen in libgdx with opengl shaders and framebuffers trouble with coordinates

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, 2d-games

I am trying to implement a shockwave effect for explosions in my 2d game
these are steps I am trying 
1) draw all stuff to a frame buffer (texture regions and meshes)
2) get texture from frame buffer and flip vertical
3) draw that resulting texture to screen with the shaders from this http://empire-defense.crystalin.fr/blog/2d_shock_wave_texture_with_shader

this is my render method

```
    resultBuf.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl20.glViewport(0, 0, resultBuf.getWidth(), resultBuf.getHeight());
    Gdx.gl20.glEnable(GL20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    batch.begin();
    renderbackground();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);



    if(imageObjDraw){
        for(Integer type:imageObjects.keySet()){
            if(type!=ImageObject.mountains&&type!=ImageObject.steelbridge1&&type!=ImageObject.steelbridge2&&type!=ImageObject.steelbridge3)for(ImageObject o:imageObjects.get(type))if(o.isInSquare(camRec))o.draw(batch);
        }
    }
    batch.end();

    if (meshDraw) {
        //DRAWING MESHES
        shaderPassThrough.begin();
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
        shaderPassThrough.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", camera.combined);
        shaderPassThrough.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
        for(Integer key:meshes.keySet()){
            if(key!=MeshInfo.bridge){
                LinkedList<myMesh> mlist=meshes.get(key);
                Texture tex=meshTextures.get(key);
                if(tex!=null)tex.bind(0);
                for(myMesh m:mlist){
                    m.render();
                }
            }
        }
        shaderPassThrough.end();
    }

    batch.begin();
    if(drawObjEnable){
        drawObjects(batch);
        vehicle.drawState0(batch);
        drawParticles(batch);
    }

    if(particleDraw)PushTheLimits.animMan.render(batch);
    if(bulletEnable)BulletManager.render(batch);

    if(imageObjDraw){
        for(Integer type:imageObjects.keySet()){
            if(type==ImageObject.steelbridge1||type==ImageObject.steelbridge2||type==ImageObject.steelbridge3)for(ImageObject o:imageObjects.get(type))if(o.isInSquare(camRec))o.draw(batch);
        }
    }

    batch.end();

    if (meshDraw) {
        //DRAWING MESHES
        shaderPassThrough.begin();
        Gdx.graphics.getGL20().glEnable(GL20.GL_BLEND);
        shaderPassThrough.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", camera.combined);
        shaderPassThrough.setUniformi("u_texture", 0);
        for(Integer key:meshes.keySet()){
            if(key==MeshInfo.bridge){
                LinkedList<myMesh> mlist=meshes.get(key);
                Texture tex=meshTextures.get(key);
                if(tex!=null)tex.bind(0);
                for(myMesh m:mlist){
                    m.render();
                }
            }
        }
        shaderPassThrough.end();
    }

    resultBuf.end();

    batch.begin();
    batch.setShader(shaderWave);
    shaderWave.begin();
    shaderWave.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", camera.combined);
    shaderWave.setUniformi("sceneTex", 0);
    shaderWave.setUniformf("center", new Vector2((explCoorX-camera.position.x+camera.effectivewidth/2f)/camera.zoom/screenW,(explCoorY-camera.position.y+camera.effectiveheight/2f)/camera.zoom/screenH));
    shaderWave.setUniformf("time", waveElaps);
    shaderWave.setUniformf("shockParams", new Vector3(10.0f, 0.8f, 0.1f));
    resultTexReg.setRegion(resultBuf.getColorBufferTexture());
    resultTexReg.flip(false, true);
    resultTexReg.getTexture().bind();
    batch.draw(resultTexReg, camera.position.x-camera.effectivewidth/2f,camera.position.y-camera.effectiveheight/2f,camera.effectivewidth,camera.effectiveheight);
    batch.end();
    batch.setShader(null);
```

here the shaders 
fragment shader

```
 #ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif
uniform sampler2D sceneTex; // 0
uniform vec2 center; // Mouse position
uniform float time; // effect elapsed time
uniform vec3 shockParams; // 10.0, 0.8, 0.1
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec2 proj;
void main() 
{ 
  float distance = distance(v_texCoords, center);
  if ( (distance <= (time + shockParams.z)) && (distance >= (time - shockParams.z)) ) {
    float diff = (distance - time); 
    float powDiff = 1.0 - pow(abs(diff*shockParams.x), shockParams.y); 
    float diffTime = diff  * powDiff; 
    vec2 diffUV = normalize(v_texCoords-center); 
    v_texCoords = v_texCoords + (diffUV * diffTime);
  }
  gl_FragColor = texture2D(sceneTex, v_texCoords);
}
```

vertex shader

```
    attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;
varying vec2 proj;
void main() {     
 //proj=u_projTrans.xy;
 v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
 gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position; 
}
```

as to define problem 
the shockwave effect always applied regard to screen coordinates I mean that center variable I pass to fragment shader -that is 0,0- must be origin of my box2d world coordinates but effect always applied to left down corner of the screen even if I move the camera to end of the map effect is at left down corner of the screen but I expect it to be at very left down out of the screen at world's origin which is 0,0 
I suspect the problem is related with I am drawing the resulting texture at camera's position and also I am using camera for projection matrix in shader but I don't have well understanding of this shader topic and graphics coordinates actually I studied it well enough this seems correct to me but I cant see the bug and need help at this point
thanks in advance please comment if I didnt tell the problem clear enough I will edit and add required info even perhaps u may want to see some screen shots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uniform called 'center' in your fragment shader is not specified in world coordinates. It's specified in the texture coordinates when you blit your render-to-texture to screen.

So regardless of where your world's camera is, the coordinates 0,0 are always the bottom left of the screen, and 1,1 is the top right.

In order to pass an appropriate value for the vec2 'center', you must transform the coordinates of the explosion (or whatever causes the shockwave) from your world-space coordinate system into texture space.

One approach for doing so would be to multiply the world coordinates by your camera WVP matrix (camera.combined). If it's a perspective camera, you might need to divide the xy of the result by the w. This should give you clip-space coordinates which are from -1,-1 to 1, 1. You then need to remap these to texture coordinates by adding 1 and halving. You could do this in the vertex shader and pass the result in through a varying, or you could do it on the CPU and pass the result through as a uniform.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply I did exactly how u said and it works now but unfortunately only on desktop now coordinates are not problem but when explosion occur during the explosion I see just a black screen I use  this code when there is explosion while applying shockwave effect but when there is no explosion I only draw the texture from buffer without setting shader to batch just drawing it with default shader with camera combined what's wrong? do I need to enable something in android manifest? and there is no error in logcat only there is a warning says gl state enables invalid enum..

Comment: I am on windows and using eclipse neon and I tried on samsung galax s5 mini and general mobile gm 5 plus in both I see only a black screen

Comment: an important notice: where I begin the shader and where I end it differs I ended it before drawing texture on batch it goes black screen on desktop as well so it is probably related with begin-end order of shader and batch perhaps this will help. what do u think can it be related with these?

Comment: sorry my mistake I said logcat is clear but actually there is an error I missed fragment shader  is not compiled it gives this error 
ERROR: 0:14: 'assign' : l-value required "v_texCoords" (can't modify a varying) then I assigned texture coordinates passed via varying to local variable vec2 now the screen is not black at all but brown I see the effect it is waving but colors are weird

Comment: okay my problem was with precision I was using mediump in fragment shader now changed to highp its okay I will edit the code to working version and accept your answer tomorrow thanx for your help